# How to compile a makefile using Visual Studio

Tags: makefile

i'm quite new to this and are therefore asking for some help, with compiling a makefile in Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.

When i type in "make" in the prompt it just give me the following "make is not recognized as an internal or external command, ...".

I've also tried "nmake" which gave me "makefile(4) : fatal error U1033: Syntax error : '=' unexpected Stop.".

Does anyone have a solution for this - just ask for any pictures or code if necessary!

Here are the first few lines of code:

```
#Some Makefile for CLASS.
#Julien Lesgourgues, 28.11.2011
MDIR := $(shell pwd)
WRKDIR = $(MDIR)/build
.base:
    if ! [ -e $(WRKDIR) ]; then mkdir $(WRKDIR) ; mkdir $(WRKDIR)/lib; fi;
    touch build/.base
vpath %.c source:tools:main:test
vpath %.o build
vpath .base build
```

Comment: `nmake` complains about syntax at line 4 in file `makefile`. Add the first 4 lines of `makefile` to the question.

Comment: Okay, I will do so.

Comment: @Mortenjørgensen I think you should use := instead of = for the WRKDIR variable

Comment: `nmake` is not `make`.  You cannot use `nmake` to build a GNU makefile, which this makefile clearly is.  In general, getting a POSIX (GNU/Linux or MacOS) makefile (which this also clearly is) to work on Windows requires much effort and knowledge.